# Image Masking using css

Tags: html, css

In my website i want to show profile pictures are in a circle shape ina particular area. In my folder it is in rectangular page. For that i am using following styles but not not working

```
<div class="circle">
     <img src="~/Content/Member/MemberPhotos/default_user_icon.jpg"/></div> 
</div>
```

tried to mask with a shape image

```
 .circle {
width:100px;height:100px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-mask-image: url(crop.png);
}
```

and also tried the following css

```
.circle {  
width:100px;  
height:100px;  
border-radius: 50px;
background-color:#000; 
clip: rect(0px,50px,100px,0px); 
}
```

both are not masked. anybody please help me

Comment: Add `overflow:hidden` to `.circle` (the second one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="circle">
 <img src="~/Content/Member/MemberPhotos/default_user_icon.jpg" style="border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%" />
</div>
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Border radius would be the best solution.
If you want to support IE8 then you will have a problem because it doesn't support border-radius. So your solution with mask would be more appropiate. Or maybe sometime in the future you will want to use a mask with another effect, other than circle. So here is a solution:

```
.circle{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
}

.circle:after{
content:"";
width:100px;
height:100px;
left:0px;
top:0px;
background-image:url(crop.png);
z-index:5;
}
```